# Linked tables in SQL server 2008 express

Tags: ms-access, linked-tables, sql-server-2008r2-express

I am migrating an ACCESS 2000 to SQL express 2008 and am having trouble with the linked tables. Is there a way to replicate the ACCESS linked tables to SQL?

Thank you

Comment: Are you stuck using A2000 as front end? It's not a very good version of Access! All the later versions are better. I would recommend the SSMA for Access as your best bet, though (as below).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the upsizing wizard or the Microsoft SQL Server Migration Assistant 2008 for Access. Once you have the tables on your SQL server you can then link them using either the normal table linking method or through code if you want to be fancy

EDIT:

If they are on the same physical box then one way is to make views of the table using the full 3 name. In the below example I’m creating a view in the database Tracker_3 that is looking at the table tblStaff_details in the database Skyline_common

USE [Tracker_3]
GO

create view [dbo].[tblStaff_details]
as 
select * from Skyline_common.dbo.[tblStaff_details]

GO

Comment: What I want to do is link a database from SQL express (Database db1, Table tbl1) to SQL express (Database db2, Table tbl2)... How can I do this?

Comment: @Olivier, I have edited my answer to show linking from one SQL server to another

Comment: No, do not use SELECT *. If new columns are added, especially in SSMS with dragging and dropping to change the ordinal position of columns, the views would break and would have to be dropped and recreated. Created the views with named columns.

Comment: @HardCode--a valid point in practice, but the example does show the proper `create view` syntax with a fully qualified name in another db on the same server, which was the point. Hopefully the OP recognizes that `select *` was a "forum shortcut" and not final code....

Answer (score 0):

> What I want to do is link a database from SQL express (Database db1, Table tbl1) to SQL express (Database db2, Table tbl2)... How can I do this?

Uh, if db1 and db2 are the names of the databases on the same server, it is **quite** easy to query between different databases.

```
select * 
from db1.dbo.tbl1 inner join db2.dbo.tbl2 
on tbl1.employeeid = tbl2.managerid
```

Hope that helps.